# Assigning Lua Script to a Button - Logitech G500s

Tags: lua, lua-scripting-library, logitech-gaming-software

I have a small macro for my Logitech G500s - i'm using it in FPS games to reduce recoil. Please see script below:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1  then
        repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-1,2)
            Sleep(16)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
end
```

Problem is that this script is works constantly.
I wish rather to push another button1 to start using script on button2 and re-press button1 to break script

I was trying to set up the flags such as:

```
unction OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then --set flag for mb1
                mb1_pressed = true
        elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6 then --set flag for mb1=false
        mb1_pressed = false
        end 

If mb1_pressed then
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and  then
        repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-1,2)
            Sleep(16)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end

end
```

but it does not work. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LUA scripting switching on/off a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435244/lua-scripting-switching-on-off-a-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then --set flag for mb1
            mb1_pressed = true
 elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6 then --set flag for mb1=false
    mb1_pressed = false
 end
```

This will set `mb1_pressed` when mouse button is pressed and unset it when it is released. So, the variable will only be true while the button is pressed.

If you want to toggle the `mb1_pressed` value on each press, you can do something like

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then --toggle flag for mb1
            mb1_pressed = not mb1_pressed
end
```