# LUA scripting switching on/off a script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm writing a script in LUA/logitech scripting API. The script should perform the following:

mouse key 4 switch on/off the script

mouse key 5 switch from one feature to other ( force move and autoattack )

The code is the follow:

```
forceMove = false
on = false
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg);
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
        forceMove = not forceMove
        while(on) do
            if(forceMove) then
                ForceMove()
            else
                StartAttack()
            end
        end
    ReleaseMouseButton(5)
    end

    if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
        on = not on
        ReleaseMouseButton(4)
    end
end

function StartAttack()
    PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(1000)
end

function ForceMove()
    MoveMouseWheel(1)
    Sleep(20)
    MoveMouseWheel(-1)
end
```

but once in game,if i activate the script with mouse button 4, i get stuck in "force move" mode, and "auto attack" mode never works. Can't figure why.

Answer (score 2):

When you press mouse button 5, you activate the 'force move' mode. If the 'on' mode is simultaneously enabled, you result in a infinite loop:

```
while(on) do
    if(forceMove) then
        ForceMove()
    else
        StartAttack()
    end
end -- loops regardless of mouse buttons
```

You will stay here forever, regardless of the mouse buttons you press.
You need to move to executing code out of the mouse event handler. The handler should only update values like forceMove, another function is needed to carry out the action. In these function, you only do ONE step, not many.
Then you check again for pressed mouse buttons, carry out the actions and so on.
Code example:

```
function update()
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
        on = not on
    end
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
        forceMove = not forceMove
    end
end

function actions()
    if on then
        if forceMove then
            ForceMove()
        end
    end
end
```

How to put it together:
You have to use some kind of loop, but ideally the game engine should do this for you. It would look something like this:

```
local is_running = true
while is_running do
    update()
    actions()
end
```

Now, if you press a button, you save the current state in some global variables which are accessed both by update and actions. The functions get called every cycle (which can be the calculation of one frame). Assuming you don't press any further buttons, update() does nothing, so `forceMove` and `on` remain the same.
This way, you have a continuous movement without a loop in action().

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but this way  i'll trigger just 1 action each time i'll push button 4/5, but instead i would like to continusly perform one of the two action while the "on" mode is true (button 4), just switching from one to another with button 5. Somewere i'll have to use a while anyway. I tought using a global variable outside the OnEvent would be fine

Comment: Well, that depends. Surely, you have to have a loop somewhere. While i don't know the logitech gaming engine, the basic idea should be roughly the same for any game engine. I have updated my answer to reflect this.